# How do I call a C++ function using Assembly?

Tags: c++, assembly, operating-system, nasm

I'm trying to build an operating system using assembly and C++, The problem is that I can't call the `kernelMain` function in C++. I used the `extern 'C'` function and I used `call kernelMain` in the assembly but keeps on giving me an error

> boot.asm:15: error: symbol `_kernelMain' not defined

The `kernelMain` function never gets called.

**boot.asm**

```
; 
mov ah, 0x0e    ; initialize ah
mov al, 'a'     ; first letter
label:          ; enter loop
    
    int 0x10    ; print char
    xor al, 32  ; switch from uppercase to lowercase or vice-versa,
    inc al      ; next letter

    mov bl, al  ; This checks if the last 5 digits of al are 11010 
    and bl, 31  ; meaning 26, without modifying it. This is the case 
    cmp bl, 26  ; for 'Z' and 'z' but not for any other ascii letter. 
    jle label   ; The code loops as long as the end of al is less than or equal to 26.

call _kernelMain ; This code doesn't work and doesn't run
jmp $           ; End of the program.

times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa
```

**kernel.cpp**

```
void printf(char* str)
{
    static unsigned short* VideoMemory = (unsigned short*)0xb8000;

    for(int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
        VideoMemory[i] = (VideoMemory[i] & 0xFF00) | str[i];
}
// I want to run this function from the boot.asm
extern "C" void _kernelMain(const void* multiboot_structure, unsigned int /*multiboot_magic*/)
{
    printf("Hello World!");
    while(1);
}
```

**makefile**

```
run: 
    gpp kernel.cpp -o kernel.o
    nasm boot.asm -f bin -o boot.bin
    qemu-system-x86_64 boot.bin
```

The piece of code that doesn't work is this

**boot.asm**

```
call _kernelMain ; This code doesn't work and doesn't run
jmp $            ; End of the program.
```

The error

> boot.asm:15: error: symbol _kernelMain' not defined

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't work", add some details about why it is not working.

Comment: Ok, ill edit it

Comment: read about ABI your C/C++ compiler uses then you will be able to figure out how to pass parameters. I do not see you set pointer properly to pass `multiboot_structure` argument.

Comment: Ok, I will, but is there a way I can call the kernelMain function?

Comment: Yes there is you have to respect ABI. For examplw pointer in first argument may be passed by some register (I do not remember which) and flowing arguments by stack. Now depending on compiler caller code is responsible for clearing stack or not. So go to documentation of your compiler to see how you have to pass arguments.

Comment: I'll just find some operating system on GitHub and just copy it. I do not know much about computers and asm, I only know C++

Comment: One more thing. `C` compilers are usually prepend underscore to symbol names. So your `_kernelMain` can be visible as `__kernelMain` in your assembly. (assuming you are linking static library).

Comment: How do you expose `_kernelMain`? As static library or is it dynamic library? It must be static library to work with your code. With dynamic library this is much more complex.

Comment: I don't know how to make static libraries or dynamic, perhaps you can help me with that

Comment: `externs "C"` just disables name mangling and sets up `C` ABI. I was asking about your build process.

Comment: The build is in the makefile

Comment: Unrelated to your build problem: `VideoMemory[i] = (VideoMemory[i] & 0xFF00) | str[i];`  note that you're *sign-extending* your `char str[]` elements to OR into the attribute byte of your text-mode memory.  It would make more sense to just do a `char*` store if you want to leave the attribute unmodified.  Or at least use `unsigned char` to tell the compiler to zero-extend before ORing.  (C ABIs for x86 have `char` as a signed type, unlike on ARM for example where `char` is unsigned.)

Comment: How do you expect nasm will even *see* the object file? (nothing is declared in the assembly source nor passed on command line)  Anyway, nasm is an assembler, not a link editor. All you could do is declare _kernelMain as extern, but it wouldn't help much: at some point you have to call a link editor to build a single binary file from several object files, and nasm won't do that.

Comment: Additionally, you are writing in assembly a boot sector, which is supposed to call a function, wbut where will the function be at runtime? If it's not in the same sector, you will probably have to play with disk io to load more sectors to memory. You may first have a look at what open source boot loaders do.